# Ic V I - can somebody explain?

Tags: theory

Could somebody explain what this is?
Where does the 'c' come from, and what does it mean?
Thanks!

Comment: More context, please?

Answer (score 7):

British (maybe other places too, I hope so!) chord notation.    a,b,c = Root position, 1st Inversion, 2nd Inversion.  So Ic, V, I is the common I64, V, I cadence.

A neat, compact system.  V7d is a 'last inversion' dominant 7th, C7/Bb.  It should be used more.

Comment: Wouldn't I⁶⁴ be second inversion IV? If so, the cadence could be written V⁶⁴ V I.

Comment: @gidds, some people write the tonic cadential 6/4 chord with a Roman numeral `V` to show the ^5 scale degree is in the bass, and the 6/4 above is considered a double appoggiatura. That's more or less a figured bass approach. `I6/4`, which is the more 'modern' way, shows `I` to mean the chord root, not bass note, is the `^1` scale degree, the 6/4 is then read to mean "second inversion." Using the older style `V6/4` logic `I/64` would indeed be a second inversion `IV`, but I've only seen this particular use for cadential `V6/4`.

Comment: And Ic  would be shorter and completely unambiguous!